# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'co_names'

Tags: python-3.x, unmarshalling, inspect

simple inspect script for pyc file
there is a problem with **co_name** function
the script is work well until the **marshal** module is **load** then fall.

```
magic: 160d0d0a
mod_time: 1493965574
source_size: 231

code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/book-resources-master/chapter4/code-exec-eg/python/inspect.py", line 24, in <module>
    inspect_code(code)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/book-resources-master/chapter4/code-exec-eg/python/inspect.py", line 8, in inspect_code
    print('{}{}(line:{})'.format(indent, code.co_names, code.co_firstlineno))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'co_names'
```

if anyone can help !
thanks

```
import marshal
import types

def to_long(s):
    return s[0] + (s[1] << 8) + (s[2] << 16) + (s[3] << 24)

def inspect_code(code, indent='    '):
    print('{}{}(line:{})'.format(indent, code.co_names, code.co_firstlineno))
    for c in code.co_consts:
        if isinstance(c, types.CodeType):
            inspect_code(c, indent + '    ')

f = open('__pycache__/add.cpython-39.pyc', 'rb')

magic = f.read(4)
print('magic: {}'.format(magic.hex()))
mod_time = to_long(f.read(4))
print('mod_time: {}'.format(mod_time))
source_size = to_long(f.read(4))
print('source_size: {}'.format(source_size))

print('\ncode:')
code = marshal.load(f)
inspect_code(code)

f.close()

import dis
dis.disassemble(code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `marshal` module nor `pyc` content, but when I try your code with Python 3.9,
I got error for reading code value. And the format of file seems different for my sample pyc built with Python 3.9.

```
magic: 610d0d0a
mod_time: 0 # <---- Unknown
source_size: 1621462747 # <---- Must be mode time
```

When I read 4 more bytes before reading value for code, I got this:

```
magic: 610d0d0a
mod_time: 0
source_size: 1621462747
4 more bytes: 14 # <----- Must be source size
```

Then I could read code value:

```
code:
    ('print',)(line:1)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

I'm not sure why you're able to run `marshal.load()` without error but may you try to read 4 more or fewer bytes before calling `marshal.load(f)`?

Comment: I think the problem not in the read before calling but in the definition of module in my version, however i already upgrade my python version but nothing is occur.!!